Want the flutter webview windows to not reload the website when press Ctrl + R
I have just started to learn desktop application development with flutter. I want to show some website on my flutter app but when I press ctrl + R the page gets reload but I do not want that. Is there any way to fix this.
I took this code from chatgpt and some from the github repo of webview_windows package. While running this code I am not getting any error I am only facing this reloading problem. If anybody knows about it please fix this.
Note: I don't have any file other than main.dart file
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_windows/webview_windows.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return MaterialApp(
     home: StaticWebsiteView(),
   );
 }
}

class StaticWebsiteView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _StaticWebsiteViewState createState() => _StaticWebsiteViewState();
}

class _StaticWebsiteViewState extends State<StaticWebsiteView> {
  final _controller = WebviewController();
  bool _isWebViewInitialized = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _initializeWebView();
  }

  Future<void> _initializeWebView() async {
    await _controller.initialize();
    await _controller.loadUrl(
        'https://humanshu-jaglan.vercel.app'); // Replace with your website URL
    setState(() {
      _isWebViewInitialized = true;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Static Website'),
      ),
      body: GestureDetector(
        behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
        onTap: () {
          // Handle other gestures or interactions as needed
        },
        child: RawKeyboardListener(
          focusNode: FocusNode(),
          onKey: (RawKeyEvent event) {
            if (event.isControlPressed && event.logicalKey.keyId == 82) {
              // Prevent Ctrl + R from triggering a reload
              return;
            }
          },
          child: _isWebViewInitialized
              ? Webview(
                  _controller) // Pass the controller as a positional argument
              : const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


